# How do you determine the convergence/divergence of this sequence and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n = (1+5/n)^{1/n}$
I think the sequence would converge to 1 but I don't know how to show that.
Does this series converge or diverge?
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+5/n)^{1/n}$

Comment: Use `\sum` for sums, not `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, your sequence will converge to $1$.

For the first, consider $\log a_n$ and show that it goes to...

For the second, since your sequence converges to $1$, then ... (Note that for a series to converge, its terms should (at least) converge to $0$).

Comment: Thank you very much! Silly me didn't recognize the divergence test!

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n\geqslant1$ for every $n\geqslant1$, the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ diverges.

Since $1\leqslant a_n\leqslant1+5/n$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and $1+5/n\to1$ when $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to1$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The second argument seems to be incomplete as the exponent of $1+5/n$ depends on $n$.

Comment: @LordSoth No. This exponent is always $\leqslant1$ and $x^a\leqslant x$ for every $x\geqslant1$ and every $0\leqslant a\leqslant1$.

Comment: Yes, I know. Perhaps you may want to include that to your answer, so that the OP will not think that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/n)^n = 1$ by "using the same arguments."

Comment: @LordSoth Actually, I like it better the way it is (and if somebody tries to use the inequality $(1+5/n)^n\leqslant1+5/n$, well... that is too bad).

Comment: +1 Wait a second; I completely screwed up. You have the inequality as the upper bound $a_n\leq 1+5/n$ in the beginning. Sorry for bugging you.

Comment: @LordSoth No problem. Each user actually caring for the way proofs are presented is an asset to the site, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Let, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $m\equiv 1/n$. Note that as $n\to\infty$, $m\to0$. Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{5}{n}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{m\to 0}\,(1+5m)^{m}=(1+5\times 0)^0=1,$$ since $m\mapsto(1+5m)^m$ is continuous at $m=0$. The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+5/n\right)^{1/n}$ is divergent, because the necessary condition for convergence that its terms converge to zero does not hold.

Comment: This uses the continuity at $m=0$, not at $m=1$. And naturally, that this continuity would be easier to grasp than the original question remains to be seen.

Comment: @Did You're right, I stand corrected. As for your concern, I agree, this is not straightforward and should be explained. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1+5x$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g:(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x,y)=\exp(y\log x)$ for each $(x,y)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$. $f$ and $g$ are (hopefully obviously) continuous. Therefore, the following composite function: $x\mapsto g(f(x),x)$ is also continuous for every $x\in(0,\infty)$ (in particular, $x=1$). But note that $$g(f(x),x)=\exp(x\log(1+5x))=(1+5x)^x.$$

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fill the dots... Rather, my point was that the size of these dots is probably not negligible for the OP, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

What does the limit of the individual terms tell you?